# Compare values to column-wise "leave-one-out" mean

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

    a  b
1   1  6
2   2  7
3   3  8
4   4  9
5   5 10
```

For each column, I want to divide each value by the column mean, where the mean is calculated by excluding the focal value from calculation of the mean ("leave-one-out" mean).

For example, the first two values in column "a"`, the calculation is like:

- `1`: `1 / ((2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 4)) =  0.2857143`
- `2`:  `2 / ((1 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 4)) = 0.6153846`
- etc.

"Leave-one-out means":

```
    mean_a         mean_b
1   3.5            8.5
2   3.25           8.25
3   3              8
4   2.75           7.75
5   2.5            7.5
```

The desired result: values / "leave-one-out" means

```
    res_a          res_b
1   0.285          0.705
2   0.615          0.848
3   1              1
4   1.454          1.161
5   2              1.333
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: EDIT:
Many thanks for the help, both answers work great!
I (unfortunately) have to accept only one, and since replicatig Rui's answer gives the desired dataframe nicely, I'll go with that..
Regardless, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, the following should do it.

```
res <- sapply(df, function(x)
    sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) x[i]/mean(x[-i]))
)
res <- as.data.frame(res)
names(res) <- paste("c", names(res), sep = "_")
res
#        c_a       c_b
#1 0.2857143 0.7058824
#2 0.6153846 0.8484848
#3 1.0000000 1.0000000
#4 1.4545455 1.1612903
#5 2.0000000 1.3333333
```

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer, I edited my question to include the desired output (and an intermediary step).

Comment: @sven_k Done, I believe that now it's a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the magic of index and vector in R

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  print(df$a[i]/mean(df$a[-i]))

}
```

I have just replicated for column a .I hope you can do it for B and  convert into dataframe .
Let me know if you need help.
Happy to help with R.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment Mukesh, it was quite useful as well!

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized possibility, which will be faster for larger data.

```
df / ((rep(colSums(df), each = nrow(df)) - df) / (nrow(df) - 1))
#         a         b
# 0.2857143 0.7058824
# 0.6153846 0.8484848
# 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 1.4545455 1.1612903
# 2.0000000 1.3333333
```